# How can i pick out an argument from a function without changing it into string?

Tags: javascript

I think it's a very silly question but please help :)

I was trying to create a function which plots graphs like sin(x) here:

```
    var x = 0;
    var zoom = 10;

    function plot(function_name) {

        function draw() {
            var y = function_name;
            c.arc(x * zoom, y * zoom, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
            c.stroke();

            x += 0.1;
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            draw();
        }

        animate();
    }

    plot('Math.sin(x)');
```

But the thing is that it picks up my argument as string (I think so). If i put it without double quotes it calculates sin(0) & gives 0 as an argument.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It picks your argument as a string, because you pass it as a string.
You can pass a function as an argument this way:

```
var x = 0;
var zoom = 10;

function plot(func) {

    function draw() {
        var y = func(x); // calculate y by applying func to x
        c.arc(x * zoom, y * zoom, 1, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        c.stroke();

        x += 0.1;
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); // move requestAnimationFrame to the end?
        draw();
    }

    animate();
}

plot(Math.sin); // pass function itself as an argument
plot(Math.cos); // or any other function

// or even custom function
function myEquation(x)
{
    return x * x + 2 * x - 4;
}
plot(myEquation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pass a function to `plot`:

```
function plot(func) {
    // ...
    var result = func(param);   // call the function with 'param' and store its result in 'result'
    // ..
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
plot(Math.sin);                 // 'func' inside 'plot' will be 'Math.sin'
plot(Math.cos);                 // 'func' inside 'plot' will be 'Math.cos'
// ...
```

If you want to do more stuff, then you can pass an anonymous function:

```
plot(function(x) {              // 'func' inside 'plot' will be a function that takes a number 'x' and return 'Math.sin(x) * Math.cos(x)'
    // do something with x first like validation for example
    return Math.sin(x) * Math.cos(x);
});
```

**Note:** You'll have to provide an `x` to the function `func` inside your `draw` function.